# Error installing matplotlib in python 3.9

Tags: matplotlib, installation, python-3.9

When I installed matplotlib in Python 3.9 and write in IDLE

```
import matplotlib
```

The computer gives me the next error:
[image]

What could I do??

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a compatible version. My guess you have a version conflicting you may `pip uninstall matplotlib` and `pip install matplotlib==xx.xx` instead of `xx.xx` put a version compatible with Python 3.9.

In the below link you can find a similar issue with Python 3.9rc2

[Issue 41917: Python 3.9rc2 fails to install matplotlib](https://bugs.python.org/issue41917)